# Clarification regarding Markov Decision Process (MDP) formulation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, reinforcement-learning, measure-theory

Most of the reinforcement learning problems are dealt with using an MDP framework.

I’m a bit confused about the formulation after reading the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02244

In an continuous MDP, state and action spaces are subsets of Euclidean space. In a Borel MDP, the spaces are Borel subsets of Euclidean space.

Question: What does this mean?What are the differences between the two? When do results from one carry over to the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Stricly speaking, the definition that you provide for continuous MDP can involve finite case, too. Consider the fact that $\{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}$.

The authors adopt the Borel spaces (or [measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space) spaces) - which can be considered as a special case of what you call continuous - to assure that the approach can use the results and concepts from [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)). This has two benefits:

1. This assures properties that reflect general intuition of a continuous MDP: that the transitions are defined as conditional probability *density* functions.
2. This allows the authors to work with the nearest-neighbor discretization of the space.

Comment: Ok. What if we consider the state space to be, say $[a,b]^n$. Would I lose generality by not saying that it’s Borel explicitly. Consider this paper:                                                              https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0af8/d10c6a4156a9cc892296008b4cb82de4095f.pdf                                                                                      The author never even mentions anything about Borel? Is the technicalities brushed under the rug, or just not considered?